# Django – create pages along with the objects using the same template

Tags: python, django

This is my first time here.

I'm stuck with a little problem in Django. I'm writing a webpage for a kennel and I have a model for dogs. These dogs appear on the front page after they have been created in admin page. I need it so that after clicking any dog picture on the front page, you could get to their profile(with the dog's name in the URL) that should use one template for each of them.

Here is my code in models, views and urls:

models.py

```
class dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dogs', blank=False, null=True)
    MALE = 'ML'
    FEMALE = 'FM'
    gender_list = (
        (MALE, 'male'),
        (FEMALE, 'female'),
        )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=gender_list, default='gender')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(default=datetime.today, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    dog_list = list(dog.objects.all())
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, {'dogs' : dog_list})

def dog_view(request, slug):
    dog_view = get_object_or_404(dog, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'dog_view' : dog_view})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^dogs/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.dog_view, name='profile'),
    url(r'^mating/', views.mating_list, name='mating'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

home.html

```
{% for dog in dogs %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile' %}{{ dog.name }}">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="{{ dog.main_image.url }}" alt="">
    <h2 align=center>{{ dog.name }} 
        <p>{{ dog.description }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I feel that it should be something very easy, although I searched over the internet and couldn't find how it is possible to have pages be automatically created along with the dog-objects.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You want each dog to have a different template? Or you want to use a template to generate each dogs page?

Comment: The second. I want to use one template to generate each dog's page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`views.py`

```
def home(request):
    dog_list = dog.objects.all()
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, {'dogs' : dog_list})

def dog_view(request, slug):
    dog_view = get_object_or_404(dog, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'dog_view' : dog_view})
```

`home.html`

```
{% for dog in dogs %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile' dog.name %}">{{ dog.name }}</a>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="{{ dog.main_image.url }}" alt="">
    <h2 align=center>{{ dog.name }} 
        <p>{{ dog.description }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^dogs/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.dog_view, name='profile'),
    url(r'^mating/', views.mating_list, name='mating'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The dogs do not appear on the page. I added my home.html to the question.
Also it started giving me NoReverseMatch error:

Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dogs/(?P<item>[-\\w]+)/$']

Comment: Thanks a ton! It finally works. 

Now I need to find out how to make every dog page understand what dog-object to use for getting information. But I'll try to do that on my own. Thanks again, @Tushortz.